# Remove rows with weight above a limit, until there is no such row

Tags: sql, oracle

My problem is clearly stated in the natural language, but I'm unable to find a solution in (ORACLE) SQL.

The data have column with a VALUE (positive number) and LIMIT (value between 0 and 1 representing percentage). The task is to remove (or identify) the rows with the VALUE that is greater than than LIMIT% of the sum of VALUES of remaining rows. Another formulation: remove rows with weight (defined by VALUE) greater than LIMIT of the total.

Note that after removing some rows, the total sum decreases and therefore another row may fail the condition and needs to be removed too.

So far I tried analytic functions (see example below), recursive with, connect by. All without success.

The solution should be in SQL, without PL/SQL. If the consensus is that no such solution exists, then a procedure will be fine.

My wrong solution using analytic functions follows:

```
WITH
DATA as (
     SELECT 23 as KEY, 100 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 22 as KEY, 101 as VALUE, 0.05 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 21 as KEY, 10 as VALUE, 0.05 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 20 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 19 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 18 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 17 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 16 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 15 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 14 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 13 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 12 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 11 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 10 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 9 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 8 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 7 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 6 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1 as KEY, 1 as VALUE, 0.15 as LIMIT from DUAL
),
REMOVED AS (
  SELECT
    d.*,
    CASE
      WHEN d.VALUE >= d.LIMIT * (SUM(d.VALUE) OVER()) THEN 'N'
      ELSE 'Y'
    END as FLAG,
    d.VALUE / d.LIMIT * (SUM(d.VALUE) OVER()) AS ACT_WEIGHT,
    SUM(d.VALUE) OVER() AS TOTOAL_SUM
  FROM DATA d
)
SELECT r.KEY
FROM REMOVED r
WHERE FLAG='N';
-- Wrong: KEY=21 is missing!
```

Comment: Hi, what order should the process go? You need to specify that. Also try to use window functions with lag and lead, those can scan the remaining rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a recursive sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. CTE) to repeatedly generate two sets of rows. The first set eliminates values above the percentage limit of the previous total and recalculates the new total and the second set of rows generated updates the `again` column to determine if there are any of the new rows that are above the new total before it iterates to generate a new pair of sets of rows.

**Query**:

```
WITH cte ( key, value, limit, lvl, total, again ) AS (
  SELECT key, value, limit, 1, SUM( value ) OVER (), 1
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT key,
         value,
         limit,
         lvl + 1,
         CASE MOD( lvl, 2 )
           WHEN 1
           THEN SUM( value ) OVER ()
           ELSE total
         END,
         CASE MOD( lvl, 2 )
           WHEN 0
           THEN MAX( CASE WHEN value > limit * total THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) OVER ()
           ELSE 1
         END 
  FROM   cte
  WHERE  ( MOD( lvl, 2 ) = 0 OR value <= limit * total )
  AND    again = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  again = 0;
```

**Output**:

```
       KEY      VALUE      LIMIT        LVL      TOTAL      AGAIN
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        20          1        .15          5         20          0
        19          1        .15          5         20          0
        18          1        .15          5         20          0
        17          1        .15          5         20          0
        16          1        .15          5         20          0
        15          1        .15          5         20          0
        14          1        .15          5         20          0
        13          1        .15          5         20          0
        12          1        .15          5         20          0
        11          1        .15          5         20          0
        10          1        .15          5         20          0
         9          1        .15          5         20          0
         8          1        .15          5         20          0
         7          1        .15          5         20          0
         6          1        .15          5         20          0
         5          1        .15          5         20          0
         4          1        .15          5         20          0
         3          1        .15          5         20          0
         2          1        .15          5         20          0
         1          1        .15          5         20          0
```

Comment: Very nice. A few months back I came up with a similar solution to a different problem, and I have used the technique a few more times since; I wrote about it on OTN. I don't know if it has a name - I call it the "seesaw recursive query" technique for lack of a better term. I would be interested if this is a well-known technique; it didn't seem to be all that familiar on OTN. A couple of links: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3966882 and https://community.oracle.com/thread/3974508

Comment: With that said, now that I understood the math problem (there is no need for an "order in which to consider the rows" since if a row violates the condition initially, it must be discarded no matter what, since it will violate it for any subset of rows it may be part of), I found that this particular problem doesn't require the seesaw technique. I am still interested in the technique though!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a recursive CTE, as MT0 has shown. MT0's solution can be simplified - this problem doesn't require the "seesaw recursive query" I mentioned in my comments to MT0.

In the recursive query, I start with the given data, but I add three columns: the sum of values (for the "current rows"), count of rows and the number 1 as a placeholder. (Any positive number can be used there.)

Then in the recursive step I keep the rows from the previous level that satisfy the limit condition (but for the "old" sum, including rows that must be discarded). I compute the sum(val) again, to be used in the next step, I count how many rows are left, and compute the difference in the count between "this" level and the previous one.

If at some point the count difference becomes zero, that means that at that level I didn't need to discard any rows. Those are the rows that are the answer to the problem. I select them in an outer query.

```
with
     data ( key, value, limit ) as (
       select ...........
     ),
     r ( key, value, limit, tot, cnt, diff ) as (
       select key, value, limit, sum(value) over (), count(*) over (), 1
         from data
       union all
       select key, value, limit, sum(value) over (), count(*) over (), 
              cnt - count(*) over ()
       from   r
       where  value <= limit * tot and diff > 0
)
select key, value, limit
from   r
where  diff = 0
;
```